# What is the meaning of the [pyspark-dataframes] tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I don't really see the difference between [pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyspark) and [pyspark-dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyspark-dataframes). Everything that is related to pyspark is related to dataframes. Can someone explain the difference?

[pyspark-dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyspark-dataframes) has no description, while for example [pyspark-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyspark-sql) has one (*Use this tag for questions related to the SQL module in PySpark*).

If there is no difference between these tags, I believe they should be merged.

Answer (score 2):

[pyspark-dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyspark-dataframes) has been synonymized to [pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyspark) now: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pyspark/synonyms

Answer (score -5):

[pyspark-dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyspark-dataframes) is a simple specialization of the more general [pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyspark) tag. If you see there exist also other specialization of [pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyspark) tag like [pyspark-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyspark-sql).

Comment: But, contrarily to OP's claim, not everything related to pyspark is related to sql, so pyspark-sql actually adds information. Why is it a compelling argument? Generally, tag specialization *specify* a sub-ensemble of the general tag.